# FDPF: Image is too large for page

Tags: image, fpdf

I'm using FPDF to create PDFs full of images. Some of these images are by far too long for a page and I need it to spread to the next page. Scaling it to a default page height won't do. 
What I'm trying to archive is to automatically insert a page break at some position. I could split the image in parts and insert every part on a new page, but I would very much like to not do that. Is there a way I haven't found yet that FPDF does that for me?

```
$pdf = new FPDF("P", "mm", "A4");
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true); 
$pdf->SetDisplayMode('real');
$pdf->Image($picUrl, 12, $pdf->GetY(), 185);
$pdf->Output($project->getName().".pdf", "D");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly would you not like to split the image in parts and insert every part on a new page? This seems like the logical way (and it can be automated in PHP if you have the proper libraries).

What you could do is insert the same image over and over again, with different offsets. Then you will have visually the same result, but I don't know if FPDF will be smart enough to not store the image several times.